# x3d blending textures transparent

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I want to blend two textures, each with specified opacity, follwing is my imaginary code. (no surprise it won't work)

```
<appearance>
    <ImageTexture url="texture1.jpg" opacity="0.7"></ImageTexture>
    <ImageTexture url="texture2.jpg" opacity="0.3"></ImageTexture>
</appearance>
```

Looks like it might have something to do with [MultiTexture](http://doc.x3dom.org/developer/x3dom/nodeTypes/MultiTexture.html) or [BlendMode](http://doc.x3dom.org/author/Shape/BlendMode.html), but I haven't figure out how it works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize an appearance node can have both texture and material properties at the same time, so the following works perfectly fine to me.

```
<shape>
  <sphere></sphere>
  <appearance>
    <ImageTexture url="texture1.jpg"></ImageTexture>
  </appearance>
</shape>

<shape>
  <sphere></sphere>
  <appearance>
    <material transparency="0.3"></material>
    <ImageTexture url="texture2.jpg"></ImageTexture>
  </appearance>
</shape>
```